# On defining Variable, incomplete listing results are shown. However when variable is not defined, then complete listing results are shown

Tags: php

I have tried creating a list

```
<?php
$list=""
$list .='<h3><strong>'. $item->n_make.' - '.$item->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$item->n_month.' - '.$item->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$item->n_short_description.'</p>
        <hr/>';             
?>
<?php
echo $list;
?>
```

With it the problem is only 1 last listing is shown and not all listings are shown

However - when i use it like this without defining the list variable

```
<?php
$list .='<h3><strong>'. $item->n_make.' - '.$item->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$item->n_month.' - '.$item->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$item->n_short_description.'</p>
        <hr/>';             
?>

<?php
echo $list;
?>
```

Then It correctly shows all listing, but it shows php Notice of Undefined variable: list

What could be the issue

**Edited**

Complete Code

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
            <?php $canEdit = $user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_promo'); ?>
                <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)) : ?>
                    <?php $class = ($canChange) ? 'active' : 'disabled'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

<?php
$list.='<h3><strong>'. $item->n_make.' - '.$item->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$item->n_month.' - '.$item->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$item->n_short_description.'</p>
        <p></p><hr/>';  
?>              


        <?php endforeach; ?>


    <?php if ($canCreate) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_promo&task=detailform.edit&id=0', false, 2); ?>"
           class="btn btn-success btn-small"><i
                class="icon-plus"></i>
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_PROMO_ADD_ITEM'); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $listOrder; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $listDirn; ?>"/>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>

<?php       
    $listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
    $numberOfListings = count($listings);
    $Reset =1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i) 
    {
        if ($Reset == 7)
        { ?> 

        <div style="margin: 0 500px 5px 12px; float: left;">
        </br></hr>

<img src="/templates/default/images/deal.jpg"/>     


  </div>

   <hr />

<p></p>

   <?php } if ($Reset == 12) { ?> 

   <div style="margin: 0 500px 5px 12px; float: left;">
        </br></hr>


<img src="/templates/default/images/scheme.jpg"/>   


   </div>

   <hr />

<p></p>

    <?php }
         echo $listings[$i] . "<hr/>";

         if($Reset>15){
                $Reset =1;
          }
          $Reset++;

    }

    ?>
```

However when tried with solution as shared to put inside or outside the loop it shows 2 more notices without any list display

```
Notice: Undefined variable: items
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

**Edited Solution**

```
<?php
$list="";
if(count($this->items) >0){ 
    foreach($this->items as $newslist)
    //$i=1;
    {
        $list .='<h3><strong>'.$newslist->n_make.' - '.$newslist->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$newslist->n_month.' - '.$newslist->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$newslist->n_short_description.'</p>
        <p></p><hr/>';
        //$i=$i+1;
    }
}else{
       $list='<div>There are no News.</div>';

}       
?>
```

Comment: put `$list=""` above/outside the (while?) loop you have.

Comment: next time please show all relevant code!

Comment: @Jeff- all relevant code pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have a loop here, although you don't show it here.

If you define `$list` inside that loop, it will be reset in every run, so only last assignment (your last item) will show up.

The simplest solution is putting the var definition outside of the loop.

```
<?php
$list=""
foreach($items as $item) {
    $list .='<h3><strong>'. $item->n_make.' - '.$item->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$item->n_month.' - '.$item->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$item->n_short_description.'</p>
        <hr/>';             
}
echo $list;
?>
```

Alternatively you could check if `$list` exists and keep definition inside the loop:

```
<?php

foreach($items as $item) {
    if(!isset($list)) {
        $list="";
    }
    $list .='<h3><strong>'. $item->n_make.' - '.$item->n_model.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'.$item->n_month.' - '.$item->n_year.'</p>
        <p>'.$item->n_short_description.'</p>
        <hr/>';             
}
echo $list;
?>
```

Comment: Pl see - edited question and all relevant code pasted, with the changes as suggested it shows more notices

Comment: I just guessed the `$items`, cause it wasn't shown before. You'll have to replace it with the array/object you initially had.

Comment: Hello, You mean to say the code you gave in 1st reply remains the solution in which only $items to be replaced with some array/object, or alternately is the solution different

Comment: yes. Solution is the same. $items just has to be whatever your source for $item is, which i cant know - since you didn't post your original loop.

Comment: Thanks, i have worked up the code basis your code given, Now there is no error notice, can you pl check if it seems okay. Thanks for your help and advise